# Kerberos uses the IP instead of hostname

Tags: java, solr, kerberos, hostname

I'm writing a Java class to access to Solr (with SolrJ) in a Kerberized Cloudera Virtual Machine with a static IP address (I'm using VMWare) from a windows machine. The problem is that Kerberos returns me the following error: **Server not found in Kerberos database (7) - UNKNOWN_SERVER.**

This is the complete error:

```
KRBError:
     cTime is Sun Mar 06 03:49:00 CET 1994 762922140000
     sTime is Thu Dec 29 16:11:14 CET 2016 1483024274000
     suSec is 413432
     error code is 7
     error Message is Server not found in Kerberos database
     cname is cloudera@CLOUDERA
     sname is HTTP/192.168.59.200@CLOUDERA
     msgType is 30
```

The problem is that Kerberos uses the IP address of the Virtual Machines (in which Kerberos is installed) instead of the FQDN (= quickstart.cloudera). In fact in Kerberos exists only HTTP/quickstart.cloudera@CLOUDERA principal.

I also tried to rename the service principal from HTTP/quickstart.cloudera@CLOUDERA to HTTP/192.168.59.200@CLOUDERA and **it worked**, but I broke all cloudera's internal services that use the HTTP original principal.

In the windows hosts file I put: 192.168.59.200 quickstart.cloudera

This is my krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = CLOUDERA
rdns = true
dns_lookup_kdc = true
dns_lookup_realm = true
dns_canonicalize_hostname = true
ignore_acceptor_hostname = true
ticket_lifetime = 86400
renew_lifetime = 604800
forwardable = true
default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac
default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac
permitted_enctypes = rc4-hmac
udp_preference_limit = 1
kdc_timeout = 3000
[realms]
CLOUDERA = {
  kdc = quickstart.cloudera
  admin_server = quickstart.cloudera
  default_domain = quickstart.cloudera
}
[domain_realm]
  .cloudera = CLOUDERA
  quickstart.cloudera = CLOUDERA
```

This is my jaas.conf:

```
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
 useKeyTab=true
 keyTab="C:/Binaries/Kerberos/cloudera.keytab"
 doNotPrompt=true
 useTicketCache=false
 storeKey=true
 debug=true
 principal="cloudera@CLOUDERA";
};
```

And this is my java test code:

```
@Test
public void testSecureSolr() {
try {

    System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
     System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","C:\\Binaries\\Kerberos\\krb5.conf");
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","C:\\Binaries\\Kerberos\\jaas.conf");

    LOG.info("-------------------------------------------------");
    LOG.info("------------------- TESTS SOLR ------------------");
    LOG.info("-------------------------------------------------");

    HttpClientUtil.setConfigurer(new Krb5HttpClientConfigurer());

    SolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(CLUSTER_URI_SOLR);
    SolrPingResponse pingResponse = solrServer.ping();

    LOG.info("Solr Ping Status: "+ pingResponse.getStatus());
    LOG.info("Solr Ping Time: "+ pingResponse.getQTime());

} catch (SolrServerException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Kerberos should be relying on DNS, not hosts files. Kerberos requires DNS in order to function properly. Per RFC 1520 and 4120. Get that IP out of your krb5.conf and change it to a DNS name, and make sure the name properly exists in DNS. You're also missing a whole section in krb5.conf: [domain_realm]

Comment: I made your suggested changes, but do you know how to install a local DNS server only for my PC and VM (I'm using vmware player)? Thanks.

Comment: That question is beyond the scope of SO.  If you are running a Windows Server OS, you can install DNS as a role service, it's pretty straightforward to install.  Once done, you will need to create an A record matching the FQDN inside the SPN.

Comment: *"how to install a local DNS server only for my PC "* -- just list the IP mappings in the local **hosts** configuration file; that file will override the DNS replies and make Kerberos happy. On Linux the file path is `/etc/hosts` and on Windows `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: I **solved** my problem simply adding the following maven dependencies in my POM (I really don't know how it was possible...): `httpcore` and `httpclient` from org.apache.httpcomponents.